# How to add different Data in Next Row of ComboBox Column in DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have a scenario in which I have MS SQL server databases a table name Items and another table name Item sizes and another table name size quantity. means to say I have a product which has an item and each item has a size and each size has its own quantity,

while making invoice I want to have a grid view which will show me item list and user will select an item and insert in to next grid view there I have a combo box which will load sizes of the item and as you know each item has its own different sizes so I want to show them in each row differently so that User doesn't mix two product sizes

Answer (score 0):

you can have a different dataSource for each row. I would suggest you to use DataTables - each of them will be for particular row (so combined they can be a set of DataSet).
One example (not using DataSet), but each row has its own dataSource:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //column 1 (normal textColumn):
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Column1");
        //column 2 (comboBox):
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboCol.Name = "cmbColumn";
        comboCol.HeaderText = "combobox column";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol);

        for (int i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++)
        {
            string text = "item " + i;
            int[] data = { 1 * i, 2 * i, 3 * i };
            CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(i, text, data);
        }
    }

    private void CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(int row, string texst, int[] data) 
    //row   index        ,and two parameters
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(texst);
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = dataGridView1[1, row] 
        as  DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        comboCell.DataSource = new BindingSource(data, null);
    }
}
```

Another solution i have solve through using DataSet (multiple dataTables), and becuase DataSet is class variable, holds all the DataTables inside - and if you maybe need some values from a specifc dataTable, you can easily get it.

```
  DataSet ds; //class variable
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ds = new DataSet();
        //column 1 (normal textColumn):
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Column1");
        //column 2 (comboBox):
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboCol.Name = "cmbColumn";
        comboCol.HeaderText = "combobox column";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol);

        //using dataTable for each datasource:             
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++)
        {
            string text = "item " + i; //data for text
            int[] data = { 1 * i, 2 * i, 3 * i }; //data for comboBox:

            //create new dataTable:
            DataTable table = new DataTable("table" + i);
            table.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(string));

            //fillig rows:
            foreach (int item in data)
                table.Rows.Add(item);

            //add table to dataSet:
            ds.Tables.Add(table);

            //creating new row in dgv (text and comboBox):
            CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(i, text, table);
        }
    }

    private void CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(int row, string texst, DataTable table)
     //row index ,and two parameters
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(texst);
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = dataGridView1[1, row] as
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        comboCell.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
        comboCell.DisplayMember = "column1"; //name of column indataTable to display!!
        comboCell.ValueMember = "column1"; // vlaue if needed 
        //(mostly you used these two propertes like: Name as DisplayMember, and Id 
        as ValueMember)
    }
```